# Custom drive shaft manufacturers in the UK

Tags: parts, drivetrain

As there is no Kit car section in the Stack yet, I thought I should ask this one here.

I am building an engine conversion project, which requires custom drive shafts.
I have the CV joints for both ends so all I need is a pair of splined shafts made to spec.

However I have had a couple of quotes and they are asking silly money, really silly, IE £300 EACH. I may be asking the wrong companies (motorsport engineering)..???

So I'm looking for advice on where can make such shafts at reasonable prices (IE under £100 each)

Answer (score 2):

Someone on another forum I frequent had a Propshaft made by [Dave Mac Props](http://www.davemacprops.com/dmphome.html) in Coventry. It cost him around £300, so I'd expect Driveshafts to be less than that.

Otherwise, have you tried more conventional Engineering firms? i.e. non car-specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

The price will be dependent on the use. If this is a high horsepower project you may need high cost axles. If you can get away with a stock strength shaft you may be able to shorten a stock axle. I know in my area (northeast U.S.) both axle/driveshaft shops deal with large truck driveline repairs as their primary bussiness. Check with a shop that specializes in truck transmission, differentials *etc*. If they don’t make their own driveshafts ask them what shop they use.